# Why is 大家们 (dàjiāmén) a thing?

Tags: meaning, expressions

Searching Baidu for [大家们](https://www.baidu.com/s?wd=%E5%A4%A7%E5%AE%B6%E4%BB%AC) (dàjiāmén) gives 8,770,000 hits.

**Question**: Why is 大家们 a thing?

It is surprising because [大家](http://8,770,000) (dàjiā) means everyone, and [们](http://dict.cn/%E4%BB%AC) (mén) is used to turn a few select words into plurals.  For example, [我们](http://dict.cn/%E6%88%91%E4%BB%AC) (wǒmén = us, we), [先生们](http://dict.cn/%E5%85%88%E7%94%9F%E4%BB%AC) (xiānshēngmén = gentlemen), and [朋友们](http://dict.cn/%E6%9C%8B%E5%8F%8B%E4%BB%AC) (péngyǒumén = friends).

It doesn't seem to make sense to say 大家们 and take a plural of "everyone".

Comment: 1.most search results for 大家们 do contain this unbroken sequence but only the 3 characters not necessarily in the same order (suggestion use the find function on any of the hits) (see answer #1) 2. the described phenomenon may be more common with 您们 which according to grammar books also is invalid

Comment: @user6065: I believe some would take issue with 您们. I doubt you wouldn't even find the word 您们 in any authoritative dictionaries. It should  always be 你们.

Comment: exactly, (comment #1: 您们 is invalid)

Comment: 您们 is a respectful way of saying 你们, it's been barely used though.

Comment: 大家们 can be used in 书法大家们，文学大家们，here they should be understood as 大书法家们 or 书法大家 - 们,  书法大家 means Gread Artist  ^_^.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's one context where it is correct: when the subject is "大家", as in:

> 古希腊那些大家们几千万数量级的著作是如何流传下来的?

[Under this definition](https://zh.wiktionary.org/zh/%E5%A4%A7%E5%AE%B6), 大家 is an honorific, or a short form of 大作家, 大專家. So 大家们 would be the plural form of this.

Comment: Although 大家们 can make sense here, it's still not a good expression because 哪些 denotes the plural already and 们 here is redundant. Also, the sentence has another issue with 几千万数量级. 几千万 is not 数量级, while 千万 is 数量级. So, 古希腊的那些大家数以千万计的著作... sounds better to me.

Answer (score 3):

大家们 is not correct.

Not all search terms with a lot of results are correct words/phrases.

You should notice that there are not many meaningful results in the search results. And the very first result is a [Q/A site](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/463384766.html) asking whether "大家们" is correct, and the accept answer says it is not. The second result is [a paper from a journal](http://www.cnki.com.cn/Article/CJFDTotal-YWZS199711037.htm) that discusses this kind of errors.

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting question. there are at least two meanings for "大家", one means "we/us", and the other means a well-know person in a field.
 so, if "大家" means "we/us", you can't say "大家们", it's not correct, because in this case "大家" has been represented "we/us"; but when you describe a group of people who are well known in a field, such as calligraphers, you can say "大家们", here are the examples

> English: The calligraphers from china have been sleeping.
>
> Chinese: 从中国来的书法大家们已经睡觉了。

but most of time we would like to say in chinese as

> 从中国来的书法家们已经睡觉了。

in most case of chinese, adding the word "们" at the end of  a creature may means   the group of this kind of creature. "人们" means people, as "人" means human being.
However, it can't be described as a simple question, to understand all about that you may need to know more about china and chinese.